# Copper ground wire with a copper brace instead of nut?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, grounding

Just wanted to get some clarification since I got some feedback on these copper ground wires seem to be bound with a copper brace (some kind of metal brace) to hold them together. Has anyone else seen this before and is this a legitimate way versus a wire nut? Was just wanting to know before I went through the hassle of cutting that brace off and putting a proper wire nut on there since I already switched out the dimmer switch and actually twisted the other wires properly together (picture is an older picture before fixing).

[image: copper ground wires bound by copper brace]
OP uploaded new photo:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a much bigger, hires photo of the red square area? It's hard to see what's in there on the current photo.

Comment: Copper crimps for ground are not uncommon, but it's completely invisible in your picture if it's there. New picture time. [Edit] a new picture in.

Comment: AI upscaled image for convenience: https://i.stack.imgur.com/doXZw.png

Comment: I'd perfer a real new picture, still,. I have doubts that was *properly* crimped, from what little can be seen in the fuzz.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard for me to tell from your original photo what is in there, but it may be this:

In an application like this to bond bare ground wires, sometimes copper "crimp sleeves" are crimped onto the two wires to mechanically and electrically bond them (see sample item below). A special crimping tool of appropriate size is used for this and the resulting connection takes up less physical space in often-crowded electrical boxes.

[image]